# Как так сделать, чтоб окно не скрывалось при клике на нем?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Как так сделать, чтоб окно не скрывалось при клике на нем и его элементах?
Например, по крестику удалить из корзины - https://prnt.sc/qkty1n

```html
if ( ! function_exists( 'techmarket_header_cart' ) ) {
 /**
  * Display Header Cart
  *
  * @since  1.0.0
  * @uses  techmarket_is_woocommerce_activated() check if WooCommerce is activated
  * @return void
  */
 function techmarket_header_cart() {
  if( techmarket_get_shop_catalog_mode() == false ) {
   if ( techmarket_is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
    $class = 'animate-dropdown dropdown ';
   }
   ?>
   <ul id="site-header-cart" class="site-header-cart menu">
    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">
     <?php techmarket_cart_link(); ?>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart">
      <li>
       <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
          <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <?php
  }
 }
}
```

if ( ! function_exists( 'techmarket_header_cart' ) ) {
    /**
     * Display Header Cart
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @uses  techmarket_is_woocommerce_activated() check if WooCommerce is activated
     * @return void
     */
    function techmarket_header_cart() {
        if( techmarket_get_shop_catalog_mode() == false ) {
            if ( techmarket_is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
                $class = 'animate-dropdown dropdown ';
            }
            ?>
            
                ">

Comment: добавь в js на клике e.stopPropagation()

Comment: И при чём здесь этот код? В консоли посмотрите какие обработчики "нацеплены" на элемент и редактируйте уже их. Также предположу, что Вы имели ввиду элемент разметки, а не окно, или у Вас окно (браузер) закрывается при клике?

Comment: Уважаемый, Вам следует самому поискать проблемный элемент, место, где он генерируется и обратить внимание на обработчики событий onclick, onsubmit и возможно какие-то ещё. По Вашему PHP-скрипту что-либо понять просто невозможно.

P.S. Восемь пробелов на табуляцию - это жесть. Был на четырёх, а сейчас и вовсе на два перешел. И горизонтальная прокрутка теперь мне не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".remove_from_cart_button");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function(e){
   document.getElementById("site-header-cart").getElementsByClassName("animate-dropdown")[0].classList.add('show')
  };
}
```

возможно поможет. но все таки иследуйте события.как говорят лучше исправить чем залотать